# creating list from separated lines

Tags: python, list, csv

I've got data that look like this:

```
-HI5UHB101EPGLJ rank=0000024 x=1813.0 y=437.0 length=81
ACGTAGATCGTGTAGCTGAGGATGTTGACAACCATGTGGACAGAGCCTCACCATCAACAT
CCTCAGCTACACGATCTGCGT
-HI5UHB101BDVPE rank=0000032 x=451.5 y=48.0 length=73
ACGTAGATCGTCTTGAGTGATTACAGATCTAATACAATGTGCAGTCTAGCTAGATGTTAT
TCTATATATATAC
-HI5UHB101AL8KC rank=0000049 x=136.0 y=586.0 length=58
ACGTAGATCGTCTCGGCTAGTAGACGAGCCATCGTCTACTAGCCGAGACGATCTGCGT
```

How do I make it into a csv sheet that looks like this:

```
'HI5UHB101EPGLJ', 'rank=0000024', 'x=1813.0', 'y=437.0', 'length=81','ACGTAGATCGTGTAGCTGAGGATGTTGACAACCATGTGGACAGAGCCTCACCATCAACATCCTCAGCTACACGATCTGCGT'
'HI5UHB101BDVPE', 'rank=0000032', 'x=451.5', 'y=48.0', 'length=73', 'ACGTAGATCGTCTTGAGTGATTACAGATCTAATACAATGTGCAGTCTAGCTAGATGTTATTCTATATATATAC'
'HI5UHB101AL8KC', 'rank=0000049', 'x=136.0', 'y=586.0', 'length=58', 'ACGTAGATCGTCTCGGCTAGTAGACGAGCCATCGTCTACTAGCCGAGACGATCTGCGT'
```

My main problem is that there is a new line character (`\n`) after the "length" and then the letter sequences themselves have new lines (`\n`) between them when I need them joined.
The letter sequences come in different lengths, which results in a variable number of sequence lines.

Any help would be appreciated. This will be run on a HUGE file.

Comment: json seems a more natural format to serialize to, no?

Comment: @roippi: why's that? CSV is perfectly servicable.

Comment: You might find the Biopython libraries useful, in particular SeqIO: http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO  I don't immediately recognize your format, but if it's a standard one there might well be tools in that library to read it.

Comment: Please provide sample code!

Comment: @MartijnPieters his attributes are named already, shrug.  If he needs to manipulate the serialized data in the future he's making more work for himself by going with csv.  Nothing 'wrong' with it past that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generator function to detect new entries by the starting `-`:

```
def per_section(iterable):
    row = []
    for line in iterable:
        if line.startswith('-'):
            if row:
                yield row
            row = line[1:].split() + ['']
        else:
            row[-1] += line.strip()
    if row:
        yield row
```

This yields complete recombined sections, ready to write to a CSV.

```
with open(inputfile) as infile, open(outputfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(per_section(infile))
```

For your sample input, that produces:

```
HI5UHB101EPGLJ,rank=0000024,x=1813.0,y=437.0,length=81,ACGTAGATCGTGTAGCTGAGGATGTTGACAACCATGTGGACAGAGCCTCACCATCAACATCCTCAGCTACACGATCTGCGT
HI5UHB101BDVPE,rank=0000032,x=451.5,y=48.0,length=73,ACGTAGATCGTCTTGAGTGATTACAGATCTAATACAATGTGCAGTCTAGCTAGATGTTATTCTATATATATAC
HI5UHB101AL8KC,rank=0000049,x=136.0,y=586.0,length=58,ACGTAGATCGTCTCGGCTAGTAGACGAGCCATCGTCTACTAGCCGAGACGATCTGCGT
```

Comment: You need single quotes around the items, and perhaps spaces after the commas.

Comment: @Jim: that's just CSV output adjusting, see the `csv` module documentation.

Comment: You have no idea how much you've made my life better! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
f= open("data.txt")
fo = open("done.txt","w")
line = f.readline()
while(len(line) > 0):
    #print line
    if (line[0] == '-'):
        label, rank, xval, yval, lenval = line.split(" ")
        lenval = lenval.strip('\n')
        #print label,rank, xval,yval,lenval
        line2 = f.readline()
        code = line2
        line2 = f.readline()
        while( len(line2.strip()) > 0):
            code = code+line2.strip()
            line2 = f.readline()
        #print code
        lineout = "'"+label[1:]+"', '"+rank+"', '"+xval+","+yval+"', '"+lenval+"', "
        lineout = lineout+"'"+code+"'\n"
        fo.write(lineout)
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
fo.close()
```

Comment: I thought you wanted second line for code.  OP exercise to combine code line with other properties..... :)

Comment: Fixed to reflect single line output per record.